# Как вернуть число в socket.inet_aton?

Tags: python

```
print socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L',-268500892))
```

239.255.0.100

Как получить назад число? Если

```
print struct.unpack('!L', socket.inet_aton('239.255.0.100'))[0]
```

4026466404

то результат не тот. В mysql также

```
SELECT INET_ATON( '239.255.0.100');
```

4026466404

Тогда как получить?

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, как на питоне.

Для 239.255.0.100 в младший (с меньшим адресом в памяти (могу ошибиться с точностью до наоборот)) байт 4-х байтового int надо положить 100 в следующий - 0, потом 255 (все 8 битиков станут единичками) а в последний 239.

На ассемблере или Си делается на раз, а как на питоне манипулировать байтами внутри целого смотрите сами.

Хотя, думаю умножение и сложение там есть. Тогда для 239.255.0.100 и адресации памяти x86 искомое число x = (100*256*256*256) + (255*256) + 239;